# Use a webpart throughtout the site

Tags: web-part, publishing-site, site-collection, custom-masterpage, html

Is it possible to use a webpart, f.x. a list of news on all sites, f.x. in a right column?

The webpart will only be created once and then "copied" to all other sub-/sites.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add  content query web part to your page which is easy to configure and after finishing your configuration you can export the web part and import it to whatever page

since you will use this approach. you can also check the following webpart http://imtech.codeplex.com which is an extended version of the content query web part that support built in server side paging

Comment: Actually this is what I was looking for! :)
This seeems to do exactly what I want! 

Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to insert the CQWP once manually in a custom pagelayout?

Comment: Yes sure you can do it like any default page layouts

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible..

you have to create custom webpart using visual studio..

go through below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415817%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Hope it helps...

Comment: Oh.. Okay! Thanks! The client has a small budget, so for now, that is not an option.

Comment: My pleasure... wc :D

Answer (score 0):

The way i work is that i don't create a webPart but a User Control that i add to a custom PageLayout that i use evrywhere i need ;)
Hope this Help.